# GIT - how to test a forked change / pull request?

Tags: git, github

I need to test the following pull request: https://github.com/grobian/carbon-c-relay/pull/274. I have cloned the master repo to my local drive: `git clone https://github.com/grobian/carbon-c-relay.git carbon-c-relay`. How do I incorporate the changes from the pull request to my local copy so that I can compile and test?

Comment: See https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/

Comment: yeah, I found I can do a `git pull origin pull/274/head`

Answer (score 2):

I found that you can pull a pull request as follows: `git pull origin pull/274/head`

Comment: You can also create a branch: `git fetch origin pull/274/head:pull-274 && git checkout pull-274`.

Comment: good to know, thanks